# What Group Policy settings can block Command Prompt from executing scripts

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-registry, group-policy

I've been struggling with a problem on my computer that apparently has no solution I could find online. I'd very much prefer not to format my hard drive and start over with a new Windows installation. So here I am asking for a solution and also hoping to shine some light is spite of research to this problem (because again apparently no one has found a solution so far).

The problem is I can't get Command Prompt to execute bat or cmd scripts.

### Example

Sample bat script `C:\Users\User1\Desktop\TestBatScript.bat` content:

```
@echo off
echo Test
pause
```

Command Prompt CLI:

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop> .\TestBatScript.bat
This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.

C:\Users\User1\Desktop>
```

### Machine configuration and modifications

- Machine runs Windows 10 Education version 1909 with latest updates applied, 64-bit
- In the past, I had installed and then eventually uninstalled CryptoPrevent, that I know modifies *Software Restriction Policies* to function. It might have caused the problem in the beginning
- I completely cleared Software Restriction Policies using `gpedit.msc`
- AppLocker rules are now empty as well (using `gpedit.msc`)
- I cleared Group Policy settings in the ways suggested by multiple tutorials online

  - Files: deleted `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy` and others going by similar names in System32
  - Registry: deleted `HKLM\Software\Policies` and `HKCU` counterpart for any user profile I'm using
  - Registry: deleted `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy*` and `HKCU` counterparts
  - Registry: deleted `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` and `HKCU` counterparts
  - Issued command `gpupdate.exe` as single standard user and administrator
- Machine is not in a domain

### More info on errors

- Fresh user accounts are affected as well
- Command Prompt running as administrator (full privileged admin, *after* accepting UAC dialog) is not affected
- Scripts inside `C:\Windows\` and descendants are not affected (does not matter if administrator or not)
- PowerShell execute fine when you do `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass` (other *scopes* work as well)

---

Thanks in advance to everyone who can give some advice on what settings other than the "standard" ones you can find online could be resulting is this annoying and almost unusable behavior from Command Prompt.